# Set default PASE IBM i shell for individual user

Tags: bash, shell, ibm-midrange

The [PASE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm?lang=en) environment ships and uses the korn shell by default.  The [ibmpaseforishell](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011555) variable can be used to change the default, but that is for all users.  How can I change the default shell for a user when then log in using SSH?

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, the best way to do this is to using `QSYS2.SET_PASE_SHELL_INFO()` SQL procedure.

```
-- set current user's shell
CALL QSYS2.SET_PASE_SHELL_INFO('*CURRENT', '/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/bash');

-- set a specific user's shell
-- (requires *SECADM special auth plus *USE and *OBJMGT to the user profile)
CALL QSYS2.SET_PASE_SHELL_INFO('THATUSER', '/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/bash');

-- set the default shell which is returned for users that do not have
-- (requires *SECADM special auth plus *USE and *OBJMGT to QSYS)
CALL QSYS2.SET_PASE_SHELL_INFO('*DEFAULT', '/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/bash');
```

A more detailed write-up about this topic is [here](https://techchannel.com/SMB/08/2017/be-like-a-turtle).

Answer (score 2):

Add a `.profile` file to their home directory *(i.e. /home/aaron/.profile)* with the following contents:

```
# detect if we're in a PASE shell
/QSYS.LIB/QSHELL.LIB/UNAME.PGM > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 -a "$SHELL" != "/QOpenSys/usr/bin/bash" ]
then
  exec /QOpenSys/usr/bin/bash
fi
```

Note the `.profile` file is what korn looks for.  If you default shell is bash then it will look for `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, and `.profile` in that order.

Comment: You trying to build your own rep or what? :)

Comment: This had me spinning my wheels for a long while so I thought others could benefit.  With that said, yes, I hope my SO reputation benefits - I like its meritocracy nature. :-)

Comment: May be version-dependent, but for what it's worth, there is no bash on my system, but there is the old Bourne shell, bsh in the same location.

Comment: @EvansWinner That's right. PASE comes with the Korn, Bourne, and C Shell. In one real sense, bash perhaps shouldn't be used under PASE since PASE isn't a Linux environment, though it's understandable that bash might be desired. The Bourne shell _should_ be a reasonable substitute. Not perfect, but it's what bash was originally intended to substitute for. Also, bash should be available for PASE from http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/download.html .

Comment: @EvansWinner You can get bash by installing the free PowerRuby download from PowerRuby.com.  Using bash from an ssh terminal session on my Mac is a breath of fresh air from using korn in QP2TERM.

Comment: This method also starts a default shell when starting QP2TERM, not just when logging in via SSH.  Is there a way to have one shell run for QP2TERM but a different one with SSH?

Comment: This isn't really setting the user's shell, it merely starts a different shell after the user's shell (or default shell if the user doesn't have one set) is started. See my answer below for how to truly set the user's shell.